# After click button the page content are gone (invisible)

Tags: asp.net

I've a page and I've postpack control in my cs file.
For example in post.aspx page users can comment.
They give name, email, url and comment and then click send button.
After click send button page content are gone.
Why is this happened?

Again I have a postback control in page_load like

```
if(!page.ispostback)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're creating dynamic controls (programmatically appended to the page) and you don't recreate them on postback.

More details about what you're doing would help though.

Comment: I have some label and div in my page.
label has post title, div has content of post.
And 
if(!page.ispostback)
{
  // get contents in here
}

First it's ok. But if user comment this post content are gone.
You can try online at http://www.kad1r.com
This is my blog and enter any post and comment. You will see what I meant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Claudio Redi mentions, you're properly setting the content of the label and the div, inside

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
```

This means, that the code will not be run, if a button is clicked. This will only run, the first time you're visiting the website.

Comment: But I did this before and there is no problem until now.
Is it related with viewstate?

Comment: I still think you should give it a try. Try putting the code that is loading your content, outside of !Page.IsPostBack - It does seem like it's related to ViewState, but I would personally not rely to much on ViewState.